# Something fishy going on - a duplicate Stack Overflow kind of website

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Googling for some question I saw this result on first page, on clicking it, the UI is exactly same as Stack Overflow. Hovering over the links show nothing unusual, but clicking on any link opens up 2-3 ads windows.

http://www.stackover.in/questions/tagged/dynamic-programming?page=3&sort=frequent&pagesize=50

It seems someone is making money, but duplicating the UI and content of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yeahhhh that looks super dodgy. Check out the reporting instructions in the dupe. Thanks!

Comment: This seems a bit stranger, the links do lead to stackexchange and stackoverflow, even when you click login. Not sure what to make of this.

Comment: @ChrisChambers I wouldn't even try to login on such a site. They may be capturing your login details before passing the request on the the real site. I suggest you change all your passwords ...